# How exactly is sample size determined in inter-rater reliability study?

Tags: sample-size, agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa

I am conducting an inter-rater reliability study where we have four raters and the form of the rating is "Yes vs. No". Correspondingly, we chose to use Kappa value as our outcome measure. Now we want to estimate the sample size needed for this study. It was really a big headache to find a well-written method. Personally, I think the best-written one is the following webpage from Dr. Gwet http://www.agreestat.com/blog_irr/sample_size_determination.html

From this article, it appears that the sample size is determined by two things: (a) our previous knowledge (or intuition, sixth sense etc.) regarding the extent of agreement among any four raters, and (b) a "relative error" which I don't quite understand what it exactly stands for (I guess it may refer to the difference between the true Kappa value and the Kappa value generated in our study).

However, as we can see from the following second webpage of the same author, it appears that the sample size can be determined by one thing named "Desired error margin" which I, once again, don't quite understand. Is it the same thing as the aforementioned "relative error"? And more importantly, how could it be, that the author wrote that the sample size is determined by TWO things in the above post but wrote in this second post that the sample size is determined by ONE thing. http://www.agreestat.com/blog_irr/sample_size_calculation.html

I am so confused, please help, and please note that, as I said, we use Kappa value (not the ICC), and our rating is "Yes vs No", and we have four raters. Thank you so much!

Comment: Is your confusion around how to plan a study around desired precision (or error margin) or why that type of study is used rather than a classical inferential study (using power calculations)?

Comment: @ AdamO, Hello AdamO, my confusion had been around desired precision. Later on, I found a software R package kappaSize that helps to address this question.  The interpretation of results is as below:  "When the estimated reliability is good (Kappa=0.8) and the estimated proportion of positive outcomes is 30%, with 4 raters, the sample size needed to ensure (with 95% confidence) that the true reliability is also good (Kappa ≥ 0.6) is 25 patients." I look forward to your further comments!! Thanks!!